# Add a directive to an UI element when the routerLink is active in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I'm currently working with angular2 and material2. My goal is to change the md-button to md-raised-button when my routerLinkActive is active. For example, if I am on "/todos", I want the "md-button" directive to be replaced by "md-raised-button".

I can't find any solution over the internet, I hope someone can guide me. I would love to avoid using a CSS class.

```
<a md-button routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="toolbar-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Home
</a>
<a md-button routerLink="/todos" routerLinkActive="toolbar-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Todos
</a>
```

Thanks for your help!

Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easier way.

```
<a md-button #rlActive="routerLinkActive" [hidden]="!rlActive.active" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="toolbar-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Home
</a>
<a md-button-raised #rlActive="routerLinkActive" [hidden]="rlActive.active" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="toolbar-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Home
</a>

<a md-button #rlActive="routerLinkActive" [hidden]="!rlActive.active" routerLink="/todos" routerLinkActive="toolbar-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Todos
</a>
<a md-button-raised #rlActive="routerLinkActive" [hidden]="rlActive.active" routerLink="/todos" routerLinkActive="toolbar-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  Todos
</a>
```

If you need this often, I'd wrap the button into a custom component to make it easier to reuse this pattern.

Comment: Thanks. It doubles the number of line of codes but at least it's a simple solution! Awesome ;)